# Why does using free() lead to infinite looping

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, free

When I run the following code, it gives me an infinite looping result. However if I comment out the free pointer lines in the `insert` function i.e. `free(ptr)` and `free(ptrnext)` then it works fine. Can anybody explain why is it so?

I am pretty sure that the print and takeInput works fine, and hence can be ignored.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct Nodes{
    struct Nodes * next;
    int val;
}Node; 

//Function to create a linked list
Node * takeInput(){
    int data;
    Node *start =NULL ;
    Node *tail=NULL;

    printf("Enter the number of nodes"); 
    int num,i;
    scanf("%d",&num);
    for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
        if(start==NULL){
            start=malloc(sizeof(Node));
            puts("Enter data");
            scanf("%d",&data);
            start->val=data;
            start->next=NULL;
            tail=start;
        }
        else{
            Node * ptr = malloc(sizeof(Node));
            puts("Enter data" );
            scanf("%d",&data);
            ptr->val=data;
            tail->next=ptr;
            tail=tail->next;
        }   

    }   
    tail->next=NULL;        
    return start;
}

//Function to print
void print(Node * head){
    Node*ptr=head;
    while(ptr!=NULL){
        printf("%d->",ptr->val);
        ptr=ptr->next;
    }
}

//Function to insert a node in given linked list 
Node * insert(Node *start){
    int i,data;

    puts("Enter pos");
    scanf("%d",&i);

    puts("Enter data");
    scanf("%d",&data);

    Node * ptr=malloc(sizeof(Node));    
    ptr->val=data;
    ptr->next=NULL;

    if(i==1){

        ptr->next=start;
        start=ptr;

        free(ptr);  

    }
    else{
        Node * ptrnext=start;
        while(i!=1){
            ptrnext=ptrnext->next;
            i--;
        }

        ptr->next=ptrnext->next;
        ptrnext->next=ptr;

        free(ptr);
        free(ptrnext);

    }
    return start;
}

int main(void){
    Node * start =takeInput();  
    start=insert(start);
    print(start);
}
```

Comment: You're deallocating nodes that are still in your linked list.

Comment: Why do you think you need to free anything when you're adding to the list, not removing from it?

Comment: Thankyou @Barmar. I got your point.

Comment: especially in the sequence: `start = ptr; free(ptr); return start;` where `insert` returns a pointer that has been freed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I run the following code, it gives me an infinite looping result. However if I comment out the free pointer lines in the insert function i.e. `free(ptr)` and `free(ptrnext)` then it works fine.

- This is **undefined behavior**. *(when you don't comment the `free()` functions)*
- Once you've freed memory you must remember not to use it any more.

> **Note :** the pointer might or might not point the same block after freeing, it's *undefined behavior*

- so don't free the pointer unless you want to `destroy` or `delete` the node.
- so don't use the `free()` in the `insert` function as you are not deleting any node.

---

- Apart from that, I don't see any function to *deallocate* the memory at the end of the program.
- **Always make sure to *deallocate* the allocated memory** at the end using a `delete()` function.
- Here's a typical implementation of `delete` function

  ```
  void delete(Node* start)
  {
       Node* temporary = NULL;
       while(start != NULL)
       {
           temporary = start->next; //saving next node address
           free(start); //freeing current node
           start = temporary; //assigning start with next node address
       }

       printf("successfully destroyed the list!"); //function exit message
  }
  ```
- Call it at the end of `main()` function or when you wish to `delete` the entire list